# Which objects give me elemental gems when I hit them?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

So far, I've noticed in Chantelise that when I swipe at grass, I occasionally get a green elemental gem, and when I hit a tree, a yellow elemental gem drops out. What are all the objects like these that yield elemental gems when I attack them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get **green gems** by hitting **tufts of grass**. These are pretty much the most frequent and easiest to find, which is great because Air spells are awesome.

You can get **yellow gems** by hitting **trees**. Unlike grass which grows in caves, there aren't a lot of trees inside places, but there generally are multiple trees in any stage.

You can get **blue gems** by destroying **barrels**. Barrels, despite being, y'know, constructed things, can be found practically everywhere. Sometimes they may have food, but in general you're getting blue gems.

You can get **red gems** by destroying **torches**. You don't see these outside often, but you can find a lot of them indoors.

Comment: I think the barrels-providing-blue-gems thing would be the barrels containing water.