# Does the elemental affinity of an enemy influence which elemental gems it drops?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I'm interested in knowing whether or not an enemy's elemental type will increase the amount of gems of that type that it drops; for example, whether or not a water-type enemy drops more water gems.

This information is useful because when I'm fighting in a room full of enemies, I often want to pick up wind gems as quickly as possible in order to cast strong AoE attacks, eliminating all threats immediately. If wind enemies drop more wind gems, it would logically make sense to target them first. Similarly, in a situation where I'm in danger and being attacked by lots of enemies, it would make sense for me to take stabs at the water enemies if there's a higher chance they might drop water gems for me to heal with.

Does an enemy's type influence the elemental gems it drops?

Comment: Probably related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26999/which-objects-give-me-elemental-gems-when-i-hit-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no effect on the enemy's elemental gemstone drop rate based on their own elemental affinity. It is pretty much chance.

You can nevertheless nudge your chances by using **Emblems**. There are 4 elemental Emblems you can find throughout the game which will significantly improve the quantity of gemstones dropped of the corresponding emblem.

The **Flame Emblem** and the **Earth Emblem** are acquired from the Fisherman (of note, all of the Flame Emblem's ingredients are in the Ignan Ruins). The other two are treasures so I'll just hide those for now. Wind is the top, Water is the bottom.

> The **Wind Emblem** is found as the prize for clearing 10 levels in the Survival Dungeon.

> The **Water Emblem** is found as a secret treasure in the Familiar Forest's bonus dungeon, specifically in the third section.